# Single UIImageView is displaying two separate images

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UITableView` in my app that for each cell pulls an image from the internet. While that image is being pulled, I have a placeholder image there (set in InterfaceBuilder). However, when I set the `UIImageView` to the new image from the web, it simply covers up the old image rather than replaces it. This would be fine except for the fact that you can actually see the old image, given that both images are `aspect-fit` and don't necessarily take up the whole `imageView`.

Is it a thread problem? Is there a method in which I can set the placeholder image so it is there immediately, even before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Get a new or recycled cell
    RosterListingCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RosterCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    LineListing *thisRosterListing = [self.rosters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.playerNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@",thisRosterListing.number];
    cell.playerNameLabel.text = thisRosterListing.name;


    cell.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    UIImage *playerImage = [self.imageCache objectForKey:thisRosterListing.playerImageURL];
    cell.imageView.image = playerImage;
    if (playerImage == nil) {

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig =
        [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
        thisRosterListing.playerImageURL = [thisRosterListing.playerImageURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"small" withString:@"medium"];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *imageData = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: thisRosterListing.playerImageURL]
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                                    NSURLResponse *response,
                                                                    NSError *error) {
                                                    // handle NSData
                                                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                                                    thisRosterListing.image = image;
                                                    [self.imageCache setObject:image forKey:thisRosterListing.playerImageURL];


                                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                        cell.imageView.image = image;
                                                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                                                    });
                                                }];
        [imageData resume];
    }


    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indicator"];
    cell.accessoryView = imageView;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // set selection color
    UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the part of the code where you update the image? `UIImageView` can’t display two images at the same time, so my guess is that you’re adding multiple image views to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Are you sure you're always setting the image on the same image view and not adding additional image views every time the cell gets reused?

Comment: OK, I added my `cellForRowAtIndexPath method`

Comment: You could try and fix the issue using Auto Layout. In fact, it could be a related issue.

Comment: What Auto Layout issue are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are setting an image on two different UIImageViews. If you click the "Debug view hierachy"

[image]

button on the bottom toolbar when xcode is running what do you see. Are the images on two different imageviews. I don't think it possible for one UIImageView to share two UIImages

Comment: You're 100% correct. There are two imageViews. I just have absolutely no idea how the second is getting added. It could only be in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, couldn't it? And I don't add a second in that code, or anywhere to my knowledge.

Comment: Well you are setting the `accessoryView` property of UITableViewCell instead of your own custom UIImageView

Comment: have you add the `UIImageView` property to your custom cell. If so then set that instead of the `accessoryView` property of `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Ahh. I see what happened. So I subclassed UITableView cell and added an imageView, which I called "playerImageView." In IB, I set this to the placeholder image. However, in code I referred to this ImageView as cell.imageView instead of cell.playerImageView. My subclass probably inherited a property named imageView.

Comment: When I fix this, however, there is no placeholder image at all. It is set in IB, but as I scroll it's blank until the image appears. To have a placeholder do I actually need to distinct imageViews and to set the placeholder to clear when the image loads?

Comment: You are setting the image to nil here: ` cell.imageView.image = playerImage;` with the image returned by the cache. Don't set the imageView with an image  until you know the image is not nil otherwise it will remove the image that is currently set there.